# Intellij idea generates empty R.java

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm working on an Android project with IDEA. I really on it's build system instead of Gradle. Everything works like a charm except resource stub generation:

```java
/*___Generated_by_IDEA___*/

package com.example;

/* This stub is only used by the IDE. It is NOT the R class actually packed into the APK */
public final class R {
}
```

`/res/` directory structure is not reflected in those files, so IDE screams in the code that symbols are missing. In manifest or any other XML files, it works correctly. The build is also fine, so I'm using decompiled `R.class` pasted back to `R.java` generated by IDEA.

**What can be wrong? How to fix it?**

Comment: No-Gradle Android projects are obsolete and not widely used. I have one legacy project where this issue is not reproducible.  There could be something specific to your project. The only way to get it resolved is to file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA, attach the sample project ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [your IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder so, in your case gen/R.java is generated corectly?

Comment: This file is not generated and the comment explains that it's not used, however I have no red code and all the references to the resources are resolved correctly.

Comment: @CrazyCoder just find out that it is fine with Java, but fails in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out.
**The solution is to drop /gen/ directory and disable it in Android facet**

`/gen/` directory contains R stub files, which for some reason are not populated. IDE itself does not use it, so the their existence is pointless. For some reason when Kotlin is in game, it uses files from `/gen` instead of relaying on IDE.